# String allocation and instance variables

Tags: objective-c

I am quite new to programming and objective C and I am having a hard time grasping a concept here about allocation, memory management and how they tie in with instance variables.  I created a category for NSString called isUrl to test for a prefix of "http:// in a string.

From there, I wanted to test this on a string.  However, given that situation I couldn't figure out if I should:
1) Declare a new string as an instance variable with @property to synthesize the accessors
2) Allocate a new string in my implementation
3) Set my variable and allocate it

What would be the difference between these methods and why would I perhaps want to use one over the other? -

As a side note, I am working with a book by O'Reilly and have tried to find answers around the web, but not a lot of luck thus far.  I seem to find examples of everything, but I an explanation of how or why they are used is more difficult.

> 1) 
>       `NSString* string = [[[NSString alloc]init]autorelease];`
>
>   string = @"http://www.google.com";
>       `if ( [string isUrl]) {
>
>           NSLog(@"Caption is a URL");
>
>           NSLog(@"URL %@",string);
>
>           string = nil;`
>
> 2) 
>      `NSString* string = @"http://www.googl.com";
>
>       [string retain];
>
>       if ( [string isUrl]) {
>
>           NSLog(@"Caption is a URL");
>
>           NSLog(@"URL %@",string);
>
>           string = nil;`
>
> 3) Something like this....
>   `@synthesize string;
>
>   string.name = "http://www.google.com";
>
>       if ( [string.name isUrl]) {
>
>           NSLog(@"Caption is a URL");
>
>           NSLog(@"URL %@",string);
>
>           string = nil;`

Answer (score 0):

String literals don't need to be released or retained.

Properties should be used whenever a value associated with an object needs to exist outside of a single function call and you don't need your program to compile under 10.4 or earlier. By your use of `nil`, it appears you don't need the string to persist, so you should only use a local variable. That's what local variables are for.

```
NSString* string = @"http://www.google.com";
if ( [string isUrl]) {
    NSLog(@"Caption is a URL");
    NSLog(@"URL %@",string);
}
```

Apple's [Objective-C memory management rules](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html) are quite simple. There's really only one rule, with a couple of corollaries.

---

> ```
> NSString* string = [[[NSString alloc]init]autorelease];
> string = @"http://www.google.com";
> ```

You don't need to allocate an object before assigning a different object to the same variable. The first object will simply get deallocated and serves no purpose.

> ```
> string.name = "http://www.google.com";
> ```

"" denotes a C string. For an NSString, you must use the at symbol. The above should be

```
string.name = @"http://www.google.com";
```